# What is the rule of thumb when it comes to giving priority to one or another preposition when talking about islands?

Tags: prepositions

I have always wondered how to choose a preposition properly when you talk about islands e.g. I live ON an island. but I was IN Tenerife. What is the rule?

Answer (score 1):

"On" gives more emphasis to the physical island itself, while "in" gives emphasis to the geographic location or political entity.

For example, Dominica is an island nation, but you should only really say "I live in Dominica", because you live in a country. However, you could say "I live on the island of Dominica", because you're referring to the island. Yes, you could say "I live on Dominica", but it would not sound as correct, because it would sound like you're making a distinction between it and some other island.

You can use "in" with Tenerife for the same reason, because you live "in" the location of Tenerife. You could still say "I live on Tenerife", because it is not a country. It's not even a territory on the same level of the Canary Islands. So the distinction tends to be: if it's a country or political entity, use "in". If not, use "on". But it's a loose rule.

Answer (score 1):

- **To live in a place or city or country** or **to be in a place**, **regardless of whether it is an island or not**.  I live in Trinidad; I live in Jamaica; I live in Cuba. I live in Paris. I live in Canada.
- And yes, one lives on an island, on a boat, on a rooftop, on a floor, or on a farm (but in a house or apartment) or on the coast. **I live on the island of Antigua**. Yes, **I live in Antigua**. But I am currently **in Trinidad** (a country: Trinidad and Tobago) or **on Trinidad** (if referring to it as an island). Do you live on an island or on the mainland? (in speaking of a coastline such as in the state of Maine in the US,for example)